# Get actual height of text inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contenteditable

So I have a content-editable div that I'm adding text to. I'd like to set up a warning when a person types a certain amount. However, I have added the ability to change the font size, boldness, italics, etc.  So is there a way I can get the actual height of just the text in the div, even if the text hasn't filled the entire div up?

Something like
`$("#my-div").textHeight()` would be awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, if you are trying for the height of the entire block of text, try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwpwowj7/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id='hold'>
    <div id='text' contenteditable>Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<button id='checkTextHeight'>Check Text Height</button>
```

CSS:

```
#hold {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
}
#text {
    min-width: 1em;
    min-height: 1em;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#checkTextHeight').click(function() {
    alert($('#text').css('height'));
});
```

Comment: Ah, I went with a solution very similiar to this. It would've been nice to do this via CSS and a single div, but this definitely works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate the content in a `display: inline` element and take it height by using jquery `$('.my-inline-element').height()`

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kbtEr

Answer (score -1):

```
var size_of_text = $('#my-div').css("font-size");
```

that should retrieve the font-size of your div, which I'm assuming to be the height of the text.

Comment: This returns the font-size, not the height of the rendered block of text. I assume the latter is what Justin is looking for.